# DataSource controls not available in .NET Windows Forms app using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2019, sqldatasource, objectdatasource

I am running Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.11.3, and I am having a problem with the data source controls (both SqlDataSource and ObjectDataSource).

Neither control shows up in the Data tab of the toolbox, yet when I use the "Choose Items..." option they are both checked.  I have gone so far as to uncheck them, save the changes and then came back in and re-checked them, but that didn't work either.  Even if I use the "Show All" option they don't show.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

I have tried the suggestions from other posts, including resetting the toolbox, adding a custom tab, and then resetting again, but nothing seems to work.  I even switched to an older version of the framework (4.6) to see if this might be the issue, but nothing works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you actually mean WinForms (as Windows Forms - Desktop  Application)?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Well, that class is used in ASP.Net, not Windows Forms.

Comment: So you can't use an ObjectDataSource in a WinForms app?

Comment: No. What for? You can probably use a BindingSource instead.

Comment: I will look at that.  It requires setting up a project data source first, right?

Comment: No. You can generate a source of data using whatever means necessary, whenever needed. You can of course use Visual Studio's Tools to handle a Project data source, through the Designer. -- Note that this object doesn't have any connection to a *View*, it doesn't need to handle *states*. To have a functionality similar to what you're probably used to, you also need a DataAdapter (working with DataTables) or a similar *connector* provided by an ORM. -- A BindingSource only handles notifications that are generated by the objects it's bound to and doesn't offer any data update feature.

Comment: Post as an answer and I'll vote it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to **Jim's comment**, I compiled the answer.Just for helpling others to solve a similar issue.

`SqlDataSource` and `ObjectDataSource` are used in ASP.Net, not Windows Forms.

Generate a source of data using whatever means necessary, whenever needed.

Use Visual Studio's Tools to handle a Project data source, through the Designer. -- **Note that this object doesn't have any connection to a View**, it doesn't need to handle states.

To have a functionality similar to what you're probably used to, you also need a `DataAdapter` (working with `DataTables`) or a similar connector provided by an `ORM`. -- A BindingSource only handles notifications that are generated by the objects it's bound to and doesn't offer any data update feature.